# load/safe html form with mysql stored data

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I build a simple html/js math-form where some calculations are beeing made with.
To simplify things I shortened the form to make it easier to understand:

```js
        function output(){
            var value1 = document.getElementById('value1').value;
            var value2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;
            var value3 = document.getElementById('value3').value;
            document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = (parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2)) * parseInt(value3);
           
             
        }
```

```html
    <select>
  <option value="volvo">Simple Addition</option>
   </select><button type="button">Load</button> <button type="button">Save</button> <button type="button">Cancel</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    Title: <input id="Title" type="text"/>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
        <input id="value1" type="text" onchange="output();" />
        <span> + </span>
        <input id="value2" type="text" onchange="output();" />
        <span> * </span>
        <input id="value3" type="text" onchange="output();" />
        <p>Result: <a id="result1"></p>
```

So, it's basically just a simple calculation. But I'm struggling to get the data stored with a mysql backend. The goal is:

a.) with a new calculation/form (non existing name in title-field), a new table should be created in mysql-db. Let's say we call the calculation "Simple Addition".
Simple-Addition should then be selectable via dropdown menu so others can load this calculation and even change/save/overwrite/correct it.

b.) So I want to be able to load, save and change any calculation to a mysql table and make it work that others can populate every stored calculation from a dropdown menu

c.) The maths should be named after the "Title" textfield

d.) autorefresh (kind of live collaboration like google sheets) all fields from database, let's say autorefresh every 5 seconds

I know this probably isn't a 5 min task, so I appreciate any of your help very very much. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Javasrcipt is a client-side language, it is won't communicate with MySQL server.
The possible solution is use AJAX call on client-side to save data by back-end PHP method.

this is only answer for the Save method. The load is similar like this, but you should use 'GET' instead of 'POST'.

AJAX call:

```
<button onclick="Save();">Save</button>

<script>
function Save()
{

var value1 = document.getElementById('value1').value;
var value2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;
var value3 = document.getElementById('value3').value;
var value4 = document.getElementById('title').value;
var inputsAndResult= [value1, value2, value3, title ];

$.ajax({
url     : 'YOUR_URL',
method    : 'POST',
data :{
 arrayData:inputsAndResult
},
success   : function(response)
{
alert("succes");
},
error : function(e)
{
alert("error")
}
});
}
</script>
```

on the backend side:

```
  <?php
$server = "localhost";
$db = "myDB";

$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $db);

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests ( number1, number2, result, name ])
VALUES ($_POST[dataArray[0]], $_POST[dataArray[1]], $_POST[dataArray[2]], $_POST[dataArray[3]])";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

These pages really good to get the basic about all of these thing like AJAX,PHP, database posting.

PHP:
https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/php-fundamentals
https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

AJAX:
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

AJAX posting into MySQL:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp